# Prevent scrolling into padding area

Tags: html, css

In the below code, we see how the overflowing content that is scrolled, is scrolling into the top/bottom padding area.

Any way to prevent that, while still keeping the scrollbar right next to the right edge?

```css
.parent {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: auto;
}

.child {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    FofofofofofofFofofofofofofFofofofofofofFofofofofofofFofofofofofofFofofofofofofFofofofofofofFofofofofofofFofofofofofofFofofofofofofFofofofofofofFofofofofofofFofofofofofofFofofofofofofFofofofofofof FofofofofofofFofofofofofofFofofofofofofFofofofofofofFofofofofofofFofofofofofofFofofofofofofFofofofofofofFofofofofofofFofofofofofofFofofofofofofFofofofofofofFofofofofofofFofofofofofofFofofofofofof
  </div>
</div>
```

More advanced CodePen example (same issue though): Using CodePen, as it includes Bootstrap: https://codepen.io/magnusriga/pen/VGdxJy

Comment: can you be more precise? you want it like there is no padding-top/bottom?

Comment: Hey bud! You see how the child is supposed to have padding top and bottom. But when you scroll, the text flows into the padding area. I would like it to not overflow the content box.

Comment: How about simply using margin instead of padding? Scrolling overflow won't be visible in the margin area.

Comment: What browser are you seeing this behavior in? Latest chrome I don't see it.

Comment: not sure I am following you ... probably a screenshot to illustrate?

Comment: @Barthy Are you sure that works? I could have sworn I tried that (not in front of computer right now).

Comment: I moved your codepen things to the sippet, you can actually include bootstrap there, too. You'll be able to see it as soon as it's peer reviewed and accepted. Margin will work for that specific case, but it may als add problems, for example if you want to have a background color for the text's container.

Comment: @Barthy ah, didn't know, thank you. Temani: I think the problem is just generally that overflowing content does not get clipped by the content box, but rather the padding box (you can see that by changing overflow to hidden). Thus, when adding scroll, we do not suddenly start clipping at the content box (which is what I wanted). Barthy, in terms of background, I could just add margin to child and overflow + background to parent. Will try it later.

Comment: @Barthy I don't think we need to have his whole codepen, the main purpose of snippet is to have the minimal example needed to show the issue, so what we have is fine, no need to add noises.

Comment: @temaniafif that's true, I just attached the pen to give some context on the overall goal. I basically stumbled into the issue as I was answering the question of another user here on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using `margin` instead of `padding`.

Note that you had the following errors in your markup:

- Duplicate IDs (`id="imgUNcover"`) on the image tags
- Two sets of classes on the image tags

I also added the `img-fluid` class to the imges to make them fill the available space.
Last but not least use the `calc()` function in the CSS to calculate the card's body height since the margin's height is added to the content box's height.

```css
.card {
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-container {
  flex: 1 0 30% !important;
  max-height: 30% !important;
  overflow: visible;
  border: none !important;
  text-align: center;
}

.card-body {
  flex: 1 0 70% !important;
  max-height: calc(70% - 2.5rem) !important;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-top: 1.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
  padding-top: 0!important;
  padding-bottom: 0!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 mb-3 mb-md-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="img-container">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-fdaa32b9bffc30131e56956e4bc1e9e4.webp" alt="blabla" class="card-img-top img-fluid">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <a href="#" class="card-title cardTitleLink">
            <h1 class="cardTitleUN">
              Some title
            </h1>
          </a>
          <p class="card-text text-muted">blabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalbla
          </p>
          <a href="#">Continue Lendo</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 mb-3 mb-md-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="img-container">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="https://www.dailydot.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/crush.jpg" alt="blabla" class="card-img-top img-fluid">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <a href="#" class="card-title cardTitleLink">
            <h1 class="cardTitleUN">
              Some title
            </h1>
          </a>
          <p class="card-text text-muted">blabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalblablabalbla
          </p>
          <a href="#">Continue Lendo</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Barthy, sorry for the delay. I had not looked through the HTML for errors, as I copied it from another OP to write her an answer (good spots!). I finally was able to dig through the spec on a few things I was uncertain about. Got it down now. For instance, border-box threw me off. I see that we must subtract margin, but not padding (if we had any) in calc, due to border-box. In the case of content-box, we would have to subtract both from height. I made some other tweaks and fixes, here is the final code: https://codepen.io/magnusriga/pen/VGdxJy?editors=1100

Comment: PS: Image was supposed to just be in the image container at top :)